# How to call events on clicking prev and next button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

In [jQuery fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) we have previous and next buttons. How can we call some events on click of these buttons?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You couldsimply attach an event to the button:

```
$('.fc-button-prev span').click(function(){
   alert('prev is clicked, do something');
});

$('.fc-button-next span').click(function(){
   alert('nextis clicked, do something');
});
```

Comment: Ok.. I thought there may be some already written function for the cause... Thanks..

Comment: @Nicola Peluchetti . if you use .fc-button-next and .fc-button-prev when you clicked below the button the click works , that's wrong .you should get .fc-button-next's and .fc-button-prev's  child span (fc-button-inner) click

Comment: Is it possible to Cancel the next/prev action, ie to let the user save changes first?

Comment: @Nicola Peluchetti - is this going to capture before the "events" callback that happens when you click Next and prev ??

Comment: @leora why the downvote :) In any case this is not a callback, it's just an event that it's fired when the user clicks on the buttons

Comment: @Nicola Peluchetti - because this doesn't stop the events callback from firing so its not deterministic that this click event will happen before the events callback coming from the regular fullcalendar from clicking the next or prev button.  Because of that you can't depend on this code above unless you start storing some state

Comment: @leora yes but as i understood the question, the need was simply to trigger an event when the user clicked next. It doesn't care about anything, just say "hello" when clicked. I don't think this had to integrated into the fullcalendar :)

Comment: fair point. i have changed the -1 to + 1.  I do think it would be better to have fullcalendar support an event so you can deterministically call something prior to the events callback happening

Comment: In the current version (2.5.0), you should use `$('.fc-prev-button')` & `$('.fc-next-button')` instead of `$('.fc-button-prev span')` & `$('.fc-button-next span')`.

Comment: for me it works if i specify like this... $(document).on('click','.fc-next-button', function () {}

Comment: Using the `viewRender` callback is definitely the better way to go

Comment: Fullcalendar v.4 reset such bindings every time you press next or prev. So it works only the first time

Answer (score 39):

The best way is:

```js
viewRender: function(view, element) {
  var b = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
  alert(b.format('L'));
},
```

Comment: This is better than getting elements from DOM with jQuery.

Comment: This should be the answer

Comment: This isn't quite right, actually, because this will fire when next or previous buttons are clicked _and_ if the view changes, say from month to week. It's not specifically for next/previous, as the question asks for.

Comment: This worked for me when going to the last item in a list view, while the jQuery solution did not since the next button was disabled (along with the event handler) before the event could fire. Since this is also built into FullCalendar, this should definitely be the accepted answer.

Comment: This Works for me! Thanks

Comment: Does not exists in v4/5? https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/viewRender

Comment: dates already fetched - tis would be after the click - op wants on click of buttons - not on render of data

Answer (score 19):

This worked for me:

```
$('body').on('click', 'button.fc-prev-button', function() {
  //do something
});

$('body').on('click', 'button.fc-next-button', function() {
  //do something
});
```

Comment: thank you man! this is the only approach that it worked for me.

Answer (score 13):

I see there are other working answers, but IMHO the simplest and more correct - at least using **FullCalendar v.4** - is to intercept `prev` and `next` is to deal them in the same way of custom buttons.

Here my setup (using toastr just for demo purposes)

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [ 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid' ],
    header: {
      left: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'prev,next'
    },
    footer: {
      left: '',
      center: '',
      right: 'prev,next'
    },
    customButtons: {
      prev: {
        text: 'Prev',
        click: function() {
                    // so something before
                    toastr.warning("PREV button is going to be executed")
                    // do the original command
                    calendar.prev();
                    // do something after
                    toastr.warning("PREV button executed")
        }
      },
      next: {
        text: 'Next',
        click: function() {
                    // so something before
                    toastr.success("NEXT button is going to be executed")
                    // do the original command
                    calendar.next();
                    // do something after
                    toastr.success("NEXT button executed")
        }
      },
    }
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

See a [Codepen here](https://codepen.io/gpcaretti/pen/vYNBVgG)

Answer (score 12):

When you click them, viewRender event is triggered. You could add your code inside it as well.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    viewRender: function(view, element) {
        //Do something
    }
});
```

Comment: I find this in answer much more accurate than the selected on. Base on view object,  how can you know if you press previous or next ?

Answer (score 10):

***SOLUTION IN FULLCALENDAR VERSION 5:***

If you're using version 5 of FullCalendar, I will suggest u to use the `datesSet` instead of using the `.click()`.

```
datesSet: function() {
    myFunction();
}
```

The `myFunction()` will be called every time when the date range of calendar has been changed or initialised. In other word, when u click on the provided prev/next buttons in the calendar, the calendar's date range will be changed and the `myFunction()` will be called.

reference: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/datesSet

If u really want to go with the `.click()` way, the following code is working for version 5 of FullCalendar.

```
$('.fc-prev-button').click(function(){
    myFunction();
});

$('.fc-next-button').click(function(){
    myFunction();
});
```

Both methods are perfectly work in my project (VERSION 5 OF FULLCALENDAR), hope this can help people who are struggling with the issue.

Answer (score 9):

When the <kbd>next</kbd> and <kbd>previous</kbd> buttons are clicked, the [events](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/) function is called. Here is an example to load data for the current year:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  loadCal();
});

function loadCal() {

  var current_url = '';
  var new_url = '';

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    // other options here...

    events: function(start, end, callback) {

      var year = end.getFullYear();

      new_url = '/api/user/events/list/' + id + '/year/' + year;

      if (new_url != current_url) {

        $.ajax({
          url: new_url,
          dataType: 'json',
          type: 'POST',
          success: function(response) {

            current_url = new_url;
            user_events = response;

            callback(response);
          }
        })
      } else {
        callback(user_events);
      }
    }
  })
}
```

When you retrieve the results in a query, make sure you include at least the last 10 days from the previous year and the first 10 days from the next year.

Comment: This is the proper way of doing instead jquery selctor. Worked like charm for me. Many thanks

Comment: This is the accurate way to do so as this facility provided by calender.js itself. No need to go for other code.+1

Answer (score 6):

**Version 3** the answer is to use:

```
viewRender: function (event, element, view){
// you code here
}
```

---

**Version 4**:
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/datesRender

```
datesRender: function (){
    // you code here
    }
```

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/upgrading-from-v3

"**viewRender** Renamed to **datesRender**. Parameters have changed."

---

**Version 5** Use :

```
datesSet: function (){
    // you code here
    }
```

"**datesRender** changed to: **datesSet** - renamed from datesRender. Called after a view's dates are initialized or when they change."
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v4

Comment: dates are already fetched for your solution - the op wants the trigger of the click - not the render

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to define your custom prev/next button:

```
$('#m_calendar').fullCalendar({
 header: {
         left: 'customPrevButton,customNextButton today',
         center: 'title',
 },
 customButtons: {
                customPrevButton: {
                    text: 'custom prev !',
                    click: function () {
                        alert('custom prev ! clicked !');

                    }
                },
                customNextButton: {
                    text: 'custom ext!',
                    click: function () {
                       alert('custom ext ! clicked !');
                    }
                },
            }
});
```

Comment: For me using `datesSet` doesn't suit to my needs since this callback is called not only when clicking prev/today/next button also when "user change the view, click a navlink [...] the current-date is manipulated via the API, such as when gotoDate is called...". Using `customButtons` is more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick update, no idea for how long but the accepted answer works for me like this:

```
$('.fc-prev-button').click(function(){
   alert('prev is clicked, do something');
});

$('.fc-next-button').click(function(){
   alert('nextis clicked, do something');
});
```

Notice slight change,

also on today click is as follows:

```
$(".fc-today-button").click(function () {
```

Hope i helped someone.

Answer (score 1):

During declaration of Calendar in events you can write the event's callback function:

```
$('#calender').fullCalendar({

events:  function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
                    callback(eventsarray);
                }
});
```

//eventsarray - This is a collection of data of the calendar. You can also call month wise function in this by passing first and last date of selected / current month and handle prev and next event.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.fc-button-next span').click(function(){

   //do your work 

});


$('.fc-button-prev span').click(function(){

   //do your work 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `click` use `on`

```
$('body').on('click', '.fc-prev-button', function() {
});

$('body').on('click', '.fc-next-button', function() {
});
```

this is useful when your calendar can dynamically initialize at any point of time.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't make it with the answers above, try this:

```
$('span.fc-button.fc-button-prev.fc-state-default.fc-corner-left').click(function() {
    alert('prev is clicked, do something');
});

$('span.fc-button.fc-button-next.fc-state-default.fc-corner-right').click(function() {
    alert('next is clicked, do something');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

FullCalendar v3.4.0

**Prev, next. today, week, month buttons:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#mycalendar').fullCalendar({


$('.fc-prev-button').click(function(){
        alert("Clicked prev button");
    });

    $('.fc-next-button').click(function(){
        alert("Clicked next button");
    });

    $('.fc-today-button').click(function(){
        alert('Today button clicked, do something');
    });

    $('.fc-listWeek-button').click(function(){
        alert('list week clicked, do something');
    });

    $('.fc-listMonth-button').click(function(){
        alert('list month clicked, do something');
    });

});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Version 6
Why not a fairly effective more globale solution with few code... pure js

```
document.querySelectorAll(('.fc-button')).forEach(button => {
    button.onclick = () => 'do something...'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[customButtons](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/customButtons)** to get event click or to change button icon, like my code below:

```
$('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar({
    themeSystem: 'jquery-ui',
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,listMonth'
    },
    height: 'auto',
    editable: false,
    eventSources: [],
    showNonCurrentDates: false,
    fixedWeekCount: false,

    // custom button
    customButtons: {
        prev: {
            // text: 'Prev', // you can choose to use text or icon to your button
            icon: 'left-single-arrow',
            click: function() {
                console.log('Prev');
            }
        },
        next: {
            // text: 'Next', // you can choose to use text or icon to your button
            icon: 'right-single-arrow',
            click: function() {
                console.log('Next');
            }
        },
    }
});

$('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar('render');
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).