# How to implement custom actions for prev /next button in <p:calendar> & <p:schedule>?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

[I found a solution to implement custom actions for the prev and next buttons in a Fullcalendar.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788761/jquery-fullcalendar-calling-events-on-clicking-prev-and-next-button-in-fullcale)

But I don't know, how I can use it for my case. I want to change the displayed date range of the `<p:calendar>` if the `<p:schedule>` switches into the next month/year and the same for the other direction. My construct looks like a simple Outlook Calendar.

[image]

I gave the `<p:calendar>` the possibility to update the `<p:schedule>`'s `initalDate` on `dateSelect`. So the schedule is hopping to the date range of the selected date. But how can I handle the event, if the `<p:schedule>` has 'month' view and the user decide to go in another month by clicking the prev/next button? The same i got if the user uses `<p:calenadar>` Buttons and Navigator.

My first idea was to create a `ManagedBean` which save the state of the current date range. And call an custom event if the previous/next buttons or the navigator get clicked. This event compare the given ranges and update. But I think this isn't possible or is it?

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: check it out http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=18176#p56567 and read comments http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=930&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20TargetVersion%20Reporter%20Owner%20Summary

Comment: I would try it, it takes a bit more time to implement, because i'm a bit busy right now.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a LazyScheduleModel Object to do that

```
ScheduleModel eventModel = new LazyScheduleModel() {

 @Override
            public void loadEvents(Date start, Date end) {
                handlePreviousNext(start, end);
            }
        };
```