# FullCalendar - prev / next

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, fullcalendar

I'm using `Fullcalendar` to display some events form json. That is all fine and I see them.

What I'm looking at doing though, is to reload the events based on the month.

So, I thought I could get the date based on what month I'm on from clicking `Prev` or `Next`.

I have the following is http://jsfiddle.net/6wE8v/408/

There is a strange occurrence when clicking back and forth getting incorrect months.

This is slightly worrying as the data needs to be accurate.

Does anyone have any ideas why this could be happening?

Thanks

Comment: [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788761/jquery-fullcalendar-calling-events-on-clicking-prev-and-next-button-in-fullcale) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your handler is being executed before the plugin has changed the month.

One way to solve this is to manually trigger the next/prev events yourself.

http://jsfiddle.net/6wE8v/408/

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar(
{
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
  },
   editable: true,        
  }); 

  $('.fc-button-prev span').click(function(){
     var date1 = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('prev').fullCalendar( 'getDate' );
     alert('prev ' + date1.getMonth());
     return false;
  });

  $('.fc-button-next span').click(function(){
     var date1 = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('next').fullCalendar( 'getDate' );
     alert('next ' + date1.getMonth());
     return false;
  });
```

Comment: Hey Kevin, Im trying to do something similar using angular. In my case i want to fetch some set of data based on the date user selects. So how do i get the value of dates(on next / prev button clicks) dynamically. example -> 28th March 2015 becomes 29th march 2015 on 'next' click. Any help would be greatly appreciated mate.

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa You really should create a new SO question, so that the question can get recorded and future users can benefit any conversations.  However, looking at their api (http://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/gotoDate/), you should be able to set the date using $(elem).gotoDate('10/24/2000').

Comment: I have already created an issue. here is the link to it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29344670/fullcalendar-display-list-based-on-the-chosen-day-using-angular.... Please feel free to contribute. Thanks