# FullCalendar - Display list based on the chosen Day using angular

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar

Hey guys i'm fairly new to Full Calendar. I'm currently using angular v1.3.15.

All i want to do is show the FullCalendar with -

1) Only the header(`fc-header`..Without the `fc-content`)
2) The header showing only the AgendaDay view by default (with the prev and next buttons). Currently I have added this onto my FullCalendar code.

```
defaultView: 'agendaDay'
```

3) I also want to pass the current selected date to the controller in order to populate a list based on the selected date.

This is something that i want to achieve -

[image]

This is what my FullCalendar script looks like -

```
  var date = new Date();
  var d = date.getDate();
  var m = date.getMonth();
  var y = date.getFullYear();

  var calendar2 = $('#calendar2').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'agendaDay',
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: ''
    },
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    select: function(start, end, allDay) {

    },
    editable: true
  });
```

For hiding the `fc-content`, i have tweaked the class `.fc-content's display to none` which works fine for now.

Any suggestion is much appreciated. Any other plugin or angular directive to make the task much simpler could also work. **Basically i just want to display a list based on the date chosen by the user using angular**

------------Updated v1--------- 
As of now i have done this to pass around the data.The problem is that the FullCalendar contents are dynamically generated.

```
  scope.getStatuses = function(current_date) {
    // HTTP GET request - to fetch all the statuses for a particular day
    var req = {
      method: "GET",
      //url: 'http://where-is-everyone.herokuapp.com/api/v1/statuses?date=2015-04-27',
      url: 'http://where-is-everyone.herokuapp.com/api/v1/statuses?date='+current_date
    };

    http(req).success(function(data, status){
      scope.status = status;
      scope.data = data;
      scope.rowCollection = data.message;
    }).
      error(function(data, status){
        scope.data = data || "Request failed";
        scope.status = status;
      });
  };

  $('.fc-button-prev').click(function(){
    var current_date = $('#calendar2').fullCalendar( 'getDate' );
    scope.formatted_current_date = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(current_date, "yyyy-MM-dd");
    scope.getStatuses(scope.formatted_current_date);
  });

  $('.fc-button-next').click(function(){
    var current_date = $('#calendar2').fullCalendar( 'getDate' );
    scope.formatted_current_date = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(current_date, "yyyy-MM-dd");
    scope.getStatuses(scope.formatted_current_date);
  });
```

This does the job, but i have observed the time taken using DevTool and it takes about 400-600ms, which is pretty slow.

Is there any way to speed it up ? because its ANGULAR right and i want to make it way faster using bindings. This is something i came up with(since the FullCalendar is dynamically generated) but i'm not sure if its the right way to do it.

```
  $(".fc-button-next").html(
    compile(
      "<span ng-click='changeListName()' class='fc-button fc-button-next fc-state-default fc-corner-right'><span class='fc-button-inner'><span class='fc-button-content'>&nbsp;►&nbsp;</span><span class='fc-button-effect'><span></span></span></span></span>"
    )(scope)
  );

  scope.changeListName = function() {
    var current_date = $('#calendar2').fullCalendar( 'getDate' );
    scope.formatted_current_date = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(current_date, "yyyy-MM-dd");
    scope.getStatuses();
  };
```

Comment: Is it possible to get a fiddle up and running to demo?

Comment: What should the list look like? What's it made up of? Can you give us a fiddle that has the data? Or do you just want to know how to pass the selected date from FC to your controller?

Comment: Its just a usual ng-repeat table list, which is working fine. As of now the date for which the data has to be fetched is hard coded. In future i need to get the date dynamically from the FullCalendar date and pass it through. Getting the date is where i would require help. Rest has been taken care of

Comment: Also i wanted to know how do i hide the ```fc-content``` from FullCalendar ?without having to patch like what i did as of now.

Comment: I'm not great with angular, so I won't answer the question directly. But the [viewRender](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/viewRender/) callback is the best way to get date changes from FC (it will fire whenever the `prev`/`next` buttons are pressed). The start/end are in the `view` argument.